# When does $x^2+2y^2 =p$ have a solution in integers?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

> Show that $x^2+2y^2=p$ has a solution in $\mathbb{Z}\;$ if and only if $\;p \equiv 1 \; \text{or} \; 3 \mod 8$.

Can someone help on this. Thnx.

Comment: Relevant: [The sum of a square and twice a square](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331557/the-sum-of-a-square-and-twice-a-square)

Comment: Have you tried showing each direction $\Rightarrow$ and $\Leftarrow$ in turn?  Which direction are you stuck on?  It would also help to know what you've tried, and what previous knowledge you have.

Comment: I proved that if $p=x^2+y^2$ then $(p)=(x+iy)(x-iy)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ so $p \equiv 1 \mod 4$

Comment: @Vali You can do this question similarly but you'll need to work in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$

Answer (score 7):

One direction: if $x^2+2y^2=p$ then $x^2\equiv -2y^2\pmod{p}$.  But $\gcd(y,p)=1$ so $(x/y)^2\equiv -2\pmod{p}$.  Hence $1=\left(\frac{-2}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)=(-1)^{\frac{(p+1)(p-1)}{8}}(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$ which implies $p\equiv 1,3\pmod{8}$.